# Java Swing Try to make a little animation with rectangle

Tags: java, swing, animation, jpanel, drawrectangle

Im try do do a mini game,but first i learn how to animate :) it will be a 2D game.
So my problem is if i just try to draw a rectangle its work when i try to animate(i did lot of code but not work :( ) its not working.

Some one can help me to fix it or add some tips how can i try to do it.

```
public class Window extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    Timer tm = new Timer(5 , this);

    int x2 = 0 , velX = 2;

    static int x= 500;
    static int y= 500;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(x2, 30, 30, 30);

        tm.start();

    }

    public Window(){

        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.pack();
        f.setTitle("Game");
        f.setSize(x,y);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(f.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    /*public void paint(Graphics g){


        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(50, 50, 50, 50);


        g2d.translate(25, 25);
        g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(45));
        g2d.draw(rect);
    }*/

    public static void main(String [] args) throws InterruptedException{
        Game g = new Game();
        g.setName("Test");
        System.out.println(g.getName());
        g.setScore();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        x2 = x2 + velX;
        repaint();

    }

}
```

Comment: Your code never adds a `Window` to a frame. If you do add it though, it works fine as far as I can tell.

Comment: I recommend you to change your class name from `Window` to something else (like MyWindow / userGUI / etc). There's an AWT class called [`Window`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html) it could give you some problems in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine except you forget to add your Component (you named it `Window`) into the Container (`JFrame` in this case). To do that add `f.add(this);` at the end of your `Window()` constructor.

Take a look at [swing-components-and-containers](http://javadevwannabe.blogspot.com.tr/2012/02/swing-components-and-containers.html) for more info.

Also I suggest you to take a look at [Double-buffer-in-standard-Java-AWT](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2136/Double-buffer-in-standard-Java-AWT) and [Game loops!](http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=24220.0)

Comment: @BalázsSzmetana, if Onur's answer answers your question please click the check mark to mark it as the answer